# Cover a rectangle with size constrained rectangular regions

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, grid-layouts

I have a big grid (indicated on the image in grey) that is divided in several blocks (each with a maximum width of 3 units). Now I would like to divide a region (indicated on the grid in red) by the corresponding blocks.

[image]

To give an example, I would like the 'block regions' (represented {X,Y,Width,Height}):

A: {2,3,2,1} B: {4,3,3,1} C: {7,3,1,1} D: {2,4,2,3} ... The only information that I have is the size of the blocks in the grid (in this case 3) and the dimensions of the region: {2,3,6,5} (= {X,Y, width, height})

Does anybody know how to do this in an efficient way? I thought about the use of mround to calculate the first boundaries of the blocks, but that lead to a dead end. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `mround`?

Comment: mround is a function used in excel, it returns a number rounded to the desired multiple. i.e. mround(10,3) = 9

Comment: Are you aware that this site is about a particular software product (Mathematica (TM))?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question.  Even if it was not intended as a *Mathematica* question let's not close it but rather write it such that it is.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/352262

Comment: And also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837871/divide-a-region-by-a-predefined-raster

Answer (score 1):

Not terribly efficient, but here's a start:

```
f1[b_] := SplitBy[Range@# + #2, Ceiling[#, b] &] &;

f2[p_List] := Join[p[[All, 1]], Length /@ p]

f3[block_, {x_, y_, w_, h_}] :=
 f2 /@ Tuples@MapThread[f1[block], {{w, h}, {x, y} - 1}]

f3[3, {2, 3, 6, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 4, 2, 3}, {2, 7, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 3, 3},
>  {4, 7, 3, 1}, {7, 3, 1, 1}, {7, 4, 1, 3}, {7, 7, 1, 1}}
> ```

---

Here's a faster, if more opaque, `f1` function:

```
f1[b_] := Partition[Range@# + #2, b, b, {Mod[#2, b] + 1, -b}, {}] &
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Mr. Wizard's comment just made me realize that my blocks start at (0,0). The conversion to (1,1) blocks is obvious, but it only makes the calculations less readable. I've changed the graphics to show where the blocks are.

Not very pretty, but simple:

```
blockWidth = 3;
{x1, y1, x2, y2} = rect = {2, 3, 2 + 6, 3 + 5};

clippedRects = Table[
   {
    {
     Clip[x1, {x, x + blockWidth}],
     Clip[y1, {y, y + blockWidth}]
     },
    {
     Clip[x2, {x, x + blockWidth}],
     Clip[y2, {y, y + blockWidth}]
     }
    },
   {x, Floor[x1, blockWidth], Ceiling[x2, blockWidth] - 1, blockWidth},
   {y, Floor[y1, blockWidth], Ceiling[y2, blockWidth] - 1, 
    blockWidth}];
```

Displaying the results:

```
gridLines = {#, {Gray, If[Mod[#, 3] == 0, Dashed, Dotted]}} & /@ 
   Range[0, 9];
Graphics[{Transparent, EdgeForm[Red], 
  Rectangle[{x1, y1} - .1, {x2, y2} + .1], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Rectangle @@@ Flatten[clippedRects, 1],}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 9, 3], Range[0, 9, 3]}, 
 GridLines -> {gridLines, gridLines}]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show the nine regions illustrated in the question.  Why?

Comment: nikie, I'm not trying to be a pest, but I still see six regions in your output rather than nine.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I fail to understand you. What do you want to compare? There are a lot of ways to partition a rectangular area and the OP hasn't asked for a particular algorithm. I think I'm missing something  ...

Comment: @belisarius I am expecting a function that takes the OP's data: "The only information that I have is the size of the blocks in the grid (in this case 3) and the dimensions of the region: {2,3,6,5} (= {X,Y, width, height})" and outputs the nine regions in the {X,Y,w,h} format.  Yes, someone's missing something, but I don't have the audacity to suggest it's not me. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, well. I think it's enough for an OT, underspecified and probably Excel related question. I'm not voting to close just because you requested it.

Comment: Damn, my reading comprehension is falling below 50%. :-P

Answer (score 0):

I thought it could be easier using `IntegerPartitions[]`, but suddenly the code got convoluted.

```
part[r_] := 
   Module[{d},
     d = IntegerPartitions[#, All, Range@3, 1][[1]] & /@ r[[3 ;; 4]];
     Flatten/@Transpose@{Tuples[r[[#]]+Most@FoldList[Plus,0,d[[#]]] & /@ {1, 2}], Tuples@d}]

part[{2, 3, 6, 5}]
(*
{{2, 3, 3, 3}, {2, 6, 3, 2}, {5, 3, 3, 3}, {5, 6, 3, 2}}
*)
part[{2, 3, 7, 9}]
(*
{{2, 3, 3, 3}, {2, 6, 3, 3}, {2, 9, 3, 3}, {5, 3, 3, 3}, 
 {5, 6, 3, 3}, {5, 9, 3, 3}, {8, 3, 1, 3}, {8, 6, 1, 3}, {8, 9, 1, 3}}
*)
```

**Edit**

A plotting function, just for completeness:

```
rect[{x_, y_, w_, h_}] := Rectangle[{x, -y - h}, {x + w, -y}]
plotrects[{x_, y_, w_, h_}] := 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black],  rect /@ part[{x, y, w, h}]}, Axes -> True, 
           PlotRange -> {{x - 3, x + w + 3}, {-y - h - 3, -y + 3}}]
plotrects[{2, 3, 6, 5}]
```

Comment: Where do we specify the block size in this code?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I nailed it with Range@3. Do you think the OP wants it as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, because he said "in this case 3" but I was more interested comparing it myself.  By the way I don't think your input and output format is the same as described in the question but that may not matter if it's not a *Mathematica* question anyway.